# Ranking data sets by means etc. (unequal sample size and variance)

Tags: anova, t-test, ranking, t-distribution, kruskal-wallis-test

I want to rank several lists of data by their tendency to be larger or their capacity to be larger when extrapolated. Is there a way to do this effectively?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more or share an example?

Comment: "Tendency to be larger" seems to refer to a calculation like $P(X>Y)>\frac12$, which may not be the same thing as ordering by means $\mu_X>\mu_Y$. Please clarify what you need.